# F# Transforming function into using higher-order functions

Tags: list, f#

I have this series of functions, `isMember`, `addElem` and `countries`:

```
let rec isMember x = function
    | y::ys -> y=x || (isMember x ys)
    | []    -> false

let addElem x ys = if isMember x ys then ys else x::ys

let rec countries = function
    | []         -> []
    | (c1,c2)::m -> addElem c1 (addElem c2 (countries m))
```

I want to rewrite countries using higher-order functions, but I'm not entirely sure how to:

My guess would be it having something to do with `List.map`, as I'm applying a function to each element of the list.

```
let countriesHigherOrder m = 
    List.map (fun x -> addElem x m)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using List.map, you can use List.fold with an accu that you initialize to [] and add elements to accu.

```
let countriesHigherOrder m = 
    List.fold (fun acc (c1,c2) -> addElem c1 (addElem c2 acc)) [] m
```

or by defining addPair:

```
let addPair (x, y) ys =
   addElem x (addElem y ys)   


let countriesHigherOrder m = 
    List.fold (fun acc (c1,c2) -> addPair (c1, c2) acc) [] m
```

Comment: Would it be possible to say `let countriesHigherOrder m = 
    List.fold (fun acc (c1,c2) -> addElem (c1,c2) acc) [] m`?

Comment: Yes it's possible. I replaced addElem with addPair. addPair calls addElem to avoid case distinctions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to flatten a list of pairs into a simple list and at the same time, preserve only one occurence of identical elements, the shortest code will involve the append operator.

```
let countries' m =
    List.unzip m ||> (@)
    |> Seq.distinct
    |> Seq.toList
```

If, on the other hand, you need the peculiar order of your doubly recursive approach, you can convert the list of tuples into two-element lists and concatenate those.

```
let countries'' m =
    List.rev m
    |> List.collect(fun (x,y) -> [y;x])
    |> Seq.distinct
    |> Seq.toList
    |> List.rev
```